# Match the checkbox text and show only those based on user input in search field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a search box and many checkbox elements.

Once a user types any text in the search box it should search the checkbox text and show only those checkboxes -- others should be hidden.

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="searchColumn" id="searchColumn"/>

<input type="checkbox" value="column1">column1
<input type="checkbox" value="column2">column2
<input type="checkbox" value="column3">column3
<input type="checkbox" value="column4">column4
<input type="checkbox" value="column5 test">column5 test
<input type="checkbox" value="(column6)">(column6)
```

Now if the user types the text "col" in the search box all checkboxes should appear as "col" is present in all checkboxes.

If the user types "abc" in the search box, no checkboxes should appear as "abc" is not present in any checkboxes.

If user types text "column1" in search box only one checkbox should appear as "column1" matches only one checkbox.

Just to add another scenario if checkbox name has "column5 test". So if user types string "test" it should show "columnn5 test" checkbox and like to highlight matched text in yellow background.

If user types a special character "(" in search box then "(column6)" checkbox should be shown

Comment: What did you try? Post your code and then we can help you.

Comment: You should actually try and do something before asking for a solution directly. This is the scope of stackoverflow...

Comment: @KrankyCode - Just found this article which does something similar  http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/08/tip-accessing-filtered-array-outside-ng-repeat/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Jquery solution using Attribute contains selector to match any elements that contains the given string value,

```
$(document).on("input", "#searchColumn", function(){
    var v = $(this).val();
    var elem = $( "input[value*='"+ v +"']" );
    if(elem.val() ){
      elem.show();
      $(":checkbox").not(elem).hide();
    }else{
        $(":checkbox").hide()
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/sq9eknfj/2/

**For Case Insensitive search -**

```
   $(document).on("input", "#searchColumn", function(){
        var v = $(this).val();
        var elem = $( ":checkbox" ).filter(function() {
            return (new RegExp(v, 'i')).test(this.value);
        });
        if(elem.val()){
          elem.show();
          $(":checkbox").not(elem).hide();
        }else{
          $(":checkbox").hide()
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for such a simple and wonderful piece of code. Can you help me with highlighting matched text in yellow background.?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can highlight the text within the input field, but if the text is next to the checkbox like in your question, we can try something out..

Comment: Yes, there is text next to checkbox that needs to be highlighted. Matched text needs to be highlighted as user types/keys in text in search box

Comment: @KrankyCode ,This is a wrong solution , Because when you type "um" show all Checkboxs.

Comment: @KrankyCode if that's the case then you can use this very simple highlight plugin - http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html , just chain it within the selection

Comment: @Vincent Your solution is case sensitive for e.g. if there is a value with "Column9".. here "C" is in caps... so it does not show up when user types "c". can it be made case insensitive.?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

**Html:**

```
<div><input type="checkbox" value="column1">column1</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" value="column2">column2</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" value="column3">column3</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" value="column4">column4</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" value="(column5)">(column5)</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#searchColumn").on("input",function(){

        var searchTxt = $(this).val();
        searchTxt = searchTxt.replace(/[.()+]/g,"\\$&");

        var patt = new RegExp("^" + searchTxt,"i");

        $(":checkbox").each(function(){

            if(patt.test($(this).val())) 
                $(this).closest("div").show(500);

            else 
                $(this).closest("div").hide(500);

        })
    })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        div {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    
    <body>
        
        <input type="text" value="" name="searchColumn" id="searchColumn"/>

<div><input type="checkbox" value="column1">column1</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" value="column2">column2</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" value="column3">column3</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" value="column4">column4</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" value="(column5)">(column5)</div>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#searchColumn").on("input",function(){
        
        var searchTxt = $(this).val();
        searchTxt = searchTxt.replace(/[.()+]/g,"\\$&");

        var patt = new RegExp("^" + searchTxt,"i");
        
        $(":checkbox").each(function(){
            
            if(patt.test($(this).val())) 
                $(this).closest("div").show(500);
                    
            else 
                $(this).closest("div").hide(500);
                    
        })
    })
})
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pretty similar to my solution... +1 for using regex. Does that make it faster?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Just to add another scenario how about if checkbox name has "column5 test". So if user types string "test" it should show "columnn5 test" checkbox and like to highlight matched text in yellow background.

Comment: @KrankyCode , if you have "column5 test" checkbox and user type "test" , Should not show checkbox Because checkbox value is "column5 test" and no "test".if my post help you mark it please!

Comment: @KrankyCode that works with my solution see below, if you say "test" it will display accordingly

Comment: @KrankyCode , i solve Problem special character "(" . try again.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change the HTML so as to be able to hide the text and the checkbox.

```
      <input type="text" value="" name="searchColumn" id="searchColumn"/>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="column1">column1
</p>

<p>
  <input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="column2">column2
</p>

<p>
  <input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="column3">column3
</p>

<p>
  <input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="column4">column4
</p>
```

Then you need a class in your CSS called `hidden`

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

And here is some jQuery (be sure to include the jQuery library in order to use jQuery):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#searchColumn').keyup(function(){ 
    $('.filter').each(function(){
      if($(this).val() == $('#searchColumn').val()){
        $('.filter').parent().addClass('hidden');
        $(this).parent().removeClass('hidden');
      }
    });

  });
});
```

Here's a working Plunker.
https://embed.plnkr.co/fDzATotA41o9tuxY6vEE/

**UPDATED** to answer the actual question!

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code I think it will help you to

```js
$('.my-textbox').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var exp = new RegExp('^' + value, 'i');
    

    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        var isMatch = exp.test($(this).val());
        $(this).parent().toggle(isMatch);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" class="my-textbox" name="searchColumn" id="searchColumn"/>


<label><input type="checkbox" class="name" value="column1">column1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="name" value="column2">column2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="name" value="column3">column3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="name" value="column4">column4</label>
```

Comment: short & sweet but not so clear for a beginner to see what is happening

Comment: @YvonneAburrow with the question I don't find him beginner!!!

Comment: maybe not but beginners do read this site

Comment: Do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

Here a vanilla JavaScript solution - no jQuery needed:

HTML (you need a wrapper in order to hide the label):

```
<input type="text" value="" name="searchColumn" id="searchColumn"/>

<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="column1">column1</div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="column2">column2</div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="column3">column3</div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="column4">column4</div>
```

CSS (hiding the checkboxes by default):

```
.checkbox {
  display:none;
}
```

JavaScript (listen for input and compare the input value with the values of all the checkboxes):

```
var checkboxDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');

document.querySelector('#searchColumn').addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  var inputValue = e.srcElement.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxDivs.length; i++) {
    var checkbox = checkboxDivs[i].children[0];
    if (checkbox.value.includes(inputValue) && inputValue.length != 0) {
        checkboxDivs[i].style.display = 'block';
    }   else {
        checkboxDivs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a32nvnka/

Comment: it certainly works very nicely but it reminds me why I love jQuery so much